# Does overloading method must have the same return type (or subtype)?

Tags: java, operator-overloading

Does overloading method must have the same return type (or subtype)?
(as overriding method does)

If yes then why at the following class B the method "findmax"can be overloaded?

```
 public class A {
    public Integer findmax(ArrayList<Integer> list, int start){...}
    }
 public class B extends A {
     public Float findmax(List<Integer> mylist, int start){...}
```

while the following one didn't compile? (is there a rule that said: overloading  method can't return primitive type? )

```
 public class A {
    public Integer findmax(ArrayList<Integer> list, int start){...}
    }
 public class B extends A {
     public float findmax(List<Integer> mylist, int start){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, because overloaded methods can't be distinguished by their return type.
but you can use a subtype as the returned type.

Comment: the answer seems to be no